# Spring Soap client - get raw response

Tags: spring, soap, client, response, raw

I created a Soap client using Spring tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

It works fine using the Java objects.

I wonder if there's a way I could obtain response (the payload, preferably without SOAP wrapper) as it is send by the service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see the request you send to the SOAP service and the response the service returns in your log application adding this property to your application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.ws=TRACE
```

or this one if you are using application.yaml

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        ws: TRACE
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to receive the SOAP response as it is before the unmarshaller convert it back to a Java object. I would like to see the raw XML. Being able to see in the log doesn't really work in a production environment. I need the XML response for further processing.